# Could the proposal Scientific Imagination be kind of a duplicate of Astronomy?

Tags: discussion

There is this new proposal that is quite hot on Area51 now. [**Scientific Imagination**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination?referrer=IPIEcsN2huMFuP7v0aO_3g2). As it's description says, it is for the people who are interested in questions involving imaginary scenarios and scientific, educational, and fun answers for those questions.

I found some questions that might be on-topic here:

- [What would happen if the sun was instantly replaced by a black hole with the same mass?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination/75972#75972)
- [If objects in Kuiper Belt and Oort Cloud could be amassed to a single planet, what would it be like?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination/75989#75989)
- [If we count Avagadro's Number of stars that are closest to Earth, how big that space would be?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination/76019#76019)

However the difference of this from Stack Exchange science sites is, the [proposal is intended to be like what-if.xkcd.com](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17667/115322). So it does not only ask for answers, but also invites answerers to let loose their imagination.

Do any of you think this proposal could be a partial duplicate of Astronomy?

Comment: I made a comment to that effect at the Scientific Imagination proposal. There are a lot of questions there that would be on-topic here, or on other SE sites. The only quibble I would have with a question being on Scientific Imagination would be if it could be answered much better on another science SE, which is the case with the questions you referenced above.

Comment: @HDE226868: The issue is, there is a danger that all of these example questions can be quickly closed as off topic, as they do no represent a real life scenario.

Comment: The first two questions you listed would actually be frowned upon here as too hypothetical. The last one would be ok.

Comment: The second is certainly too hypothetical, but I would argue that the first one is on-topic here if and only if the OP wanted to know about, say, the effects on the orbits of the planets - i.e. gravitational effects. For example, there is a question on Astronomy.SE called "What would be the effects on Earth if Jupiter was turned into a star?", which sees awfully similar, yet garnered 149+ views, four answers, and two votes. Then again, I don't have the rep to see if there were any "close" votes against it.

Comment: Amending my last comment: I now have the rep and have found that as of this moment, there are no close votes against it.